# I used a webpack, but why isn't the request reduce?

Tags: webpack, frontend, web-frontend

I used a webpack, but why wouldn't I get fewer requests?

Executed script command "npm run dev".

I was Access `localhost:9000`

But why aren't the http requests decreasing?

As far as I know, a webpack binds files.
I checked the Network tab, but the bundle doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UVm2.png)

Please, Check my setting...

`package.json` file

```js
{
  "name": "dev-server-test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DevServer</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div class="container">
      TEST..
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.container');
div.innerText = 'load Webpack!!';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  }
```

your webpack.config.js takes an index.js as an entry and outputs a bundle.js file.
Now if your index.js looks like this:

```
console.log("Script loaded");
```

this will be outputed on the bundle.js file. There is no binding or module bundling even if you use webpack.

However if your index.js was:

```
import './script1.js'
import './script2.js'
```

when you run webpack it will bundle these scripts into one script bundle.js which actually reducing server requests as you will have 1 script instead of loading them separately.

Comment: 1. I don't have tried to import js files through index.js
2. html don't have scripts

thanks your answer

Comment: thanks, your solution solved my error.
i appreciate you.